# How to add EditText on spinner popup in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-spinner

I need to add `EditText` on top of the `Spinner` popup for searching purpose. Is this possible? How to do this? give me any idea for this.

Comment: try this link may be it helps you https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/J3PQ4jzQ8pk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it with custom class extends the `Spinner` class and override the `performClick()` method. In the `performClick()` method, I'm showing the Dialog. That dialog have `EditText` and `ListView`. I added the searching technique for EditText.